# How to get real path to mp3 on Android

Tags: android

For query I need get _id, last digital from path
On my android 4.4 I see in debugger that mp3 path looks like: content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/audio:10719 and I try to get real path as:

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_MUSIC_GET && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            Uri urri = data.getData();
            String[] musIdAr=urri.getPath().split(":");
            String orderBy = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA + " DESC";
            Cursor cr = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,null,"_id = ?",new String(musIdAr{musIdAr.length-1]},orderBy);
            cr.moveToFirst();
            String src=cr.getString(1);//real path id
            cr.close();
            initPlayer();
        }
    }
```

It works good, 
but on android 4.3 I see that path looks like content://media/external/audio/media/900
without audio:10719 - it dosn't work
Is there universal way to get real path?

Comment: What does it matter that 'mp3 path's look different? You forgot to tell which variable represents that path. Also you did not tell which variable represents the real path. And finally you did not tell if your code works for both versions.

Comment: You did not supply the info i asked for. Why not?